# Ubuntu bootable USB stick

Tags: usb

I have successfully created USB bootable stick using ubuntu 14.04.1 iso file. 
But when I boot with this USB it asks about login info but won't accept any user name. Almost hanging !!! 
What is the problem? What user name and password is supposed to enter? And how?

-- AVK

Comment: Where did you get that ISO and please describe all steps you did. There is no login or password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Username: ubuntu

Password: ubuntu

or

Username: ubuntu

No Password

Source: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/560473-ubuntu-14-4-01-login